# HSSFCellStyle to HTML CSS style

Tags: java, apache-poi

i am trying to convert an excel workbook to HTML page. The plan is to make the HTML as close possible replica of the excel sheet as possible. For this, i need to migrate the style settings for each Cell (HSSFCellStyle) to CSS.

The first thing that came to my naive mind is that if there is a library avaiable to do this conversion, my work would be reduced by leaps and bounds.

Is anyone aware of such a library or utility? Am I following the right apprach or is there something avaiable to do this (excel - html) already?

Thanks,
amit

Answer (score 0):

Given that Excel itself can save as an HTML page (and presumably do this well), would it make more sense to run up an Excel COM control (via [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/), say), and get the COM control to save as HTML ? I realise this solution *doesn't* use POI, but it may be the simplest solution to achieve a decent result.